# Курсор в виде картинки не хочет дружить с нами

Tags: html, css, cursor

Здравствуйте!

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему:
У нас задача сделать вместо курсора черный кросовок, а если ссылка белый кросовок.

Прописали в самом верху файла со стилем значение cursor ,
а он при навидении тормозит на пол секунды показывает стандартный, и потом уже тот что нужно.

Видео с проблемой засняла тут: https://youtu.be/UNh1alhlLGQ

Очень надеюсь на Вашу поддержку.
[image: Мой код]

Comment: попробуйте добавить к a:hover и a:focus ещё просто а

Comment: И :hover c фокусом можно убрать. CSS свойство cursor работает только, когда курсор находится над элементом.

Comment: изображения для курсоров больше 32x32 пикселей